# What's the right way to override colors with MUI withStyle and TypeScript and next.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui

I have:

```
const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({
  label,
  size,
  variant = 'primary',
  disabled = false,
}: ButtonProps) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <MaterialButton
      className={`${classes.buttonBase} size-${size}`}
      disabled={disabled}
    >
      {label}
    </MaterialButton>
  );
};
```

and

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  buttonBase: {
    background:'#000000',
    color: '#ffffff',
```

However, if `variant` is `secondary`, I want to basically swap the `background` and `color`. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it in your theme.
The example below is for using the variant="contained" with color="secondary"

```
export const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        containedSecondary: {
          backgroundColor: '#808080',
          color: '#FFFFFF',
          '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: '#565656',
          },
        },
      }
    }
  }

<Button variant="contained" color="secondary">Test button</Button>
```

Or if you want to set the style in your component you can set up a variant for the secondary like this. Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-jqbujs?file=/demo.js:399-514)

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  primary: {
    backgroundColor: "purple",
    color: "#FFF"
  },
  secondary: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    color: "#FFF"
  }
});

<Button className={classes.secondary}>Secondary</Button>
<Button className={classes.primary}>Primary</Button>
```

Comment: So set it theme level and then I don't need a separate component?

Comment: Yes, setting it on the theme you can use the Button component with the props like described above. Also you can extend it for other cases in a similar way, like if you want it for the outlined buttons by setting the `outlinedSecondary`

Comment: But what if I need it as a separate component (so that I can add some additional functionality / UI)?

Comment: Do you want to use a styled component?   ( Although, note that changing on the theme it shouldn't block you from adding any functionality / UI changes ). Would you like to explain in more detail what are the scenarios you want to achieve?

Comment: @Shamoon also please have a look at my updated answer, i have also included a codesandbox.